# How to Input 2 Variables in a scanf that reads 3

Tags: c, validation, input, scanf

So, I want to have an input where it can take 3 inputs of different variables (int and char). But I want to have an option where an output prints out something even if only 2 variables are given. How do I make this possible using scanf and if possible something that has basic C whilst not using Ctrl+D and not too advanced, Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char y;
  int i;
  int x;
  int a;
  printf("Enter Input: ");
  a = scanf("%c %d %d", &y, &i, &x);
  if(a == 2) {
    printf("%c %d", y, i);
  }
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo It continues to wait for the third value to be input.

Comment: I'd suggest NOT using `scanf()`. https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html is a good starting point for alternatives.

Comment: Read a complete line with `fgets()`, and then parse that. Possibly using `sscanf()`.

Comment: If you want us to limit a proposed solution to what you already learned, you need to tell us what all you learned. If the number of values to scan depends on the first value (`%c`) you could use 3 separate `scanf` calls and skip the 3rd call depending on the 1st value.

Comment: @Dylan How do you want to indicate the end of input if not using Ctrl+D?  Do you want to use <Enter> (`'\n'`) to indicate the end of input?

Answer (score 3):

The general advice for avoiding common pitfalls with `scanf` is to instead read entire lines of input with `fgets`, and then parse those lines in-memory with `sscanf` (or use tools that follow the same pattern, e.g., `getline` (POSIX) + `strspn` / `strcspn` / `strtol`, etc.).

Unlike how `scanf` waits for more input when it has an unfulfilled conversion and `stdin` has not reached EOF (or error), `sscanf` does not wait on an unfulfilled conversion because it is not like there will suddenly be more *string* to parse.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[256];
    printf("Enter Input: ");

    if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
        return 1;

    char y;
    int i;
    int x;

    int rc = sscanf(buffer, "%c%d%d", &y, &i, &x);

    if (rc < 2)
        return 1;

    if (rc < 3)
        printf("%c | %d\n", y, i);
    else
        printf("%c | %d | %d\n", y, i, x);
}
```

Example usage:

```
 % ./a.out
Enter Input: a 2
a | 2
 % ./a.out
Enter Input: a 2 4
a | 2 | 4
```